# assigning a value from dictionary to equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

i want to assign a value to a string equation but i am stuck with the logic.

```
dic1 = {'d': '2', 'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
equation_string = 'ab+cd'
```

i want to the output like:

```
'12+32' = 44
```

My Logic:

1 -> writing a for loop to assign the values to the string but i don't know how to skip '+' sign in the string.

```
for itr in range(0,len(equation_string)):
          equation_String[itr] = dict1[equation_str[itr]]
```

Comment: If you try your code, you will see that it doesn't let you reassign elements of an immutable object. Try checking whether the character is in the dictionary, and building a new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve it. You need to firstly replace the *key* in `equation_string` of `dic1` with the corresponding *value* using [`string.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace). When you made all the replacements within the *string*, execute the string expression using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). Below is the sample code:

```
>>> dic1 = {'d': '2', 'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
>>> equation_string = 'ab+cd'
>>> for k, v in dic1.iteritems():
...     equation_string = equation_string.replace(k, v)
... 
>>> equation_string
'12+32'   # Updated value of equation_string
>>> eval(equation_string)
44
```

Comment: You could just do `equation_string = ''.join(dic1.get(x, x) for x in equation_string)`.